# Mock datas on IMongoCollection Substitute

Tags: c#, mongodb, nsubstitute

I’m still a beginner in C# and unit testing and I have a problem that I don’t know how to solve.
I've a Mongo Database and I just want to mock this database.
I’ll start by showing you my code before I explain my problem.

Here is my unit test class:

```
private FollowManager _followManager;
private FollowsDao _followSubstitute;
private UsersDao _userSubstitute;
private IMongoDatabase _database;
private IMongoCollection<Follow> _followMongoCollection;
private IMongoCollection<User> _userMongoCollection;

[OneTimeSetUp]
public void OneTimeSetup()
{
    _database = Substitute.For<IMongoDatabase>();
    _followMongoCollection = Substitute.For<IMongoCollection<Follow>>();
    _userMongoCollection = Substitute.For<IMongoCollection<User>>();
    _followSubstitute = new FollowsDao(_database, _followMongoCollection);
    _userSubstitute = new UsersDao(_database, _userMongoCollection);
    _followManager = new FollowManager(_followSubstitute, _userSubstitute);
}

[TestCase(1, 2)]
[TestCase(3, 4)]
public void AssertThatBuildFollowReturnsValidFollow(int followerId, int followedId)
{
    UserFollow userFollow = new UserFollow {Follower = followerId, Followed = followedId};
    Follow follow = _followManager.BuildFollow(userFollow);

    Assert.IsNotNull(follow);
}
```

Here is my function that I want to test in my `FollowManager`:

```
public Follow BuildFollow(UserFollow follow)
{
    User follower = _userDao.FindUserByNumber(follow.Follower).Result;
    User followed = _userDao.FindUserByNumber(follow.Followed).Result;
    Follow newFollow = new Follow { Follower = follower, Followed = followed, Date = DateTime.Now };

    InsertOrUpdateFollow(newFollow);

    return newFollow;
}
```

The `FindUserByNumber` method will search in the database for a user that matches the id passed as a parameter:

```
public async Task<User> FindUserByNumber(int number)
{
    List<User> result = await _collection.Find(user => user.Number == number && user.Active).ToListAsync();

    return result.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

My problem is:
When I call `Follow follow = _followManager.BuildFollow(userFollow);` in my unit test, this line `InsertOrUpdateFollow(newFollow);` in my manager throw an error. It's normal because properties `Follower` and `Followed` are null because my database is mocked.

I have a JSON file that contains the list of users of the database and I want to be able to recover my users from this file and not from the database.

With this, I've my users in my JSON file:

```
List<User> users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\users-list-api-result.json"));
```

So, my question is:
How can I test this function with JSON mocked file ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered using a real mongodb (in-memory, or one that gets configured and reset every fixture setup and teardown) for testing instead of mocking? You code is all about interacting with the database, so mocking that out will reduce how relevant your test is. Another option is to use a mongodb-agnostic adapter/facade and mock that (but you're still left having to test the mongodb implementation of that interface using a real db instance. It will just let you isolate some of the non-mongodb specific logic). Let me know if you'd like more info on any of these options.

Comment: @DavidTchepak I would be interested to know how you went about setting something like that up? I've been looking for a MongoDB alternative to the Inmemory Database provided by Entity Framework for ages! Usually means I have to run tests like this in a blow away environment which seems quite aggressive

Comment: @JamiePeacock I haven't used mongo db before. I don't think having a blow away env is bad if the tests still run fast enough. If not I'd try an adaptor and test logic through that, then run tests against the db-specific implementation of that in a separate test suite.